# DbContext ChangeTracker not working without ForeignKey properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having kind of an issue with the ChangeTracker of DbContext.
I had a model defined with properties and Data Annotations for the Foreign Keys. For business reasons, I had to change that for FluentAPI, and since then, the ChangeTracker does not recognize changes to the navigation properties anymore.

The scalar properties work just fine and the navigation properties are saved for the database when I call `SaveChanges()`, but when I try to do the following:

```
var t = this.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(
            c => c.State == EntityState.Modified || 
    c.State == EntityState.Added || 
    c.State == EntityState.Deleted
);
```

Calling `t.Any()` always returns false.

Is there a way to solve this or I will have to go back to Data Annotations?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

As requested at comments, I'm showing a class where the problem occurs:

```
public class C016
    {
        #region Fields

        private string _c016Codigo;
        private string _c016Descricao;
        private P029_TipoUnidadeMedida _p029TipoUnidadeMedida;
        private P030_TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida _p030TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida;

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public virtual ObservableCollection<C015_Produto_DadosFiscais> C015_Produto_DadosFiscais { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Código da Unidade de Medida
        /// </summary>
        [Required, MaxLength(6)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string C016_Codigo
        {
            get { return this._c016Codigo; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this._c016Codigo) return;
                this._c016Codigo = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Descrição da Unidade de Medida
        /// </summary>
        [Required, MaxLength(60)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string C016_Descricao
        {
            get { return this._c016Descricao; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this._c016Descricao) return;
                this._c016Descricao = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Código da Unidade de Medida, Autonumerador
        /// </summary>
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int C016_Id { get; set; }

        public byte P029_Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tipo da Unidade de Medida, Fracionário ou Inteira
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("P029_Id")]
        public virtual P029_TipoUnidadeMedida P029_TipoUnidadeMedida
        {
            get { return this._p029TipoUnidadeMedida; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, this._p029TipoUnidadeMedida)) return;
                this._p029TipoUnidadeMedida = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tipo de métrica da Unidade de medida
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public virtual P030_TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida P030_TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida
        {
            get { return this._p030TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, this._p030TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida)) return;
                this._p030TipoMetricaUnidadeMedida = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

As you can see, I have two navigation properties. One is set by Data Annotations (P029), and another (P030) is set somewhere else by FluentAPI.
In my WPF Window, I have two ComboBoxes, one for each navigation property. When I change de "P029" one, the ChangeTracker returns 1 changed entry, but when I change de "P030" one, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data annotations mapping vs. fluent? And code that was supposed to change navigation properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Instead of using:

```
var t = this.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Modified || 
                c.State == EntityState.Added || 
                c.State == EntityState.Deleted);

return t.Any();
```

I've used:

```
return this.Context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
```

And now everything is working.

Comment: Along those lines, I'm currently googling to try to find out which of my entity-objects being tracked by the ChangeTracker actually has changes to be saved (I've modified a child-collection), despite the entity having a state of Unchanged...